# intersection of primitive in a unit wrapping 3D space

Tags: mathematics, fragment-shader, raytracing

is there people good enough for a math problem (for a shader)?
I want to write an algorithm that would **intersect** primitives (triangles, squares, circle, sphere, cube, cylinder) inside a unit wrapping space, **no raymarching**, at least axis aligned.

The goal is to write a shader. The benefit, is that, since it's analytic, I can do trick by passing parameters with the texture per pixel.

I already do this by abusing simpler variants of of interior design, by cranking the space between side low, and get dense (simple) foliage and grass for free, or brick walls, or any greebles. **Except I'm confined to simple convex shapes with interior style shader**, with this I could have more interesting parallax to abuse **artistically**. I use the flow of the polygon surface to create interesting shapes, and UV texture to break pattern artistically. Work wonder for low specs machine!

I figure out how to do it with a single point at the boundaries of the space, using the planet alignment problem (akin to the two clock hand overlap problem). But I failed to generalized it.

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CuPJQtNWIAA5eRI.jpg]

[image: https://29a.ch/2013/9/25/wild-webgl-raymarching/boring.jpg]

This problem is similar to this math problem
https://amininima.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/the-laser-gun/

But without the reflection.
[image]

Other potential benefits is that it have a period we can find mathematically, we could probably infer an analytical "overdraw", by "discarding depth" have a "traversed thickness", if we generalized the, such as we can also shift the position of the primitive at each "jump", we could probably find a consistent "integral 3D noise", which would made cloud noise in convex volume much cheaper than marching.

> *Optionally* "the graal" would be at least 1 period coil repeated on axis aligned.
>   But we can't intersect cosine "cheaply", I tried using x²
>   approximations but my math melted. A unit coil being an unwrap unit
>   cylinder diagonal, was the next step explored, ie to intersect axis
>   aligned cylinder then find on its surface the diagonal: [image: Cylinder coil tracing sktech]
>   the idea above is, taking the perpendicular going through the cylinder center, we observe that the tracing "regularly" step through it, using that stepping and the slope of the ray, we can infer point on the wrapping surface of the cylinder, the entire idea is to find the step pattern so we can intersect the diagonal within a certain distance.

EDIT: While talking below in the comment, I realized that I probably could shift the 1D wrapping space to the 2D projection of the ray direction, then find the period of the primitive's "axis" projected on that line, and since I already found the case for 1D, use that to infer the remaining intersection. Just an idea not developed yet. Should make a drawing to show what I mean, it's not clear yet in words.

Comment: I think you're asking for a bit too much here. To handle any primitive generically, we'll almost certainly need to use raymarching. If we can't use raymarching, then we might be limited in the primitives that offer a closed-form solution to this problem, if indeed any do. Can you give us more context about what you're trying to do and why these constraints are necessary?

Comment: Well I know it's possible because some people have done it, the dev of that clay game (he made that first pencil drawing that explain cylinder and sphere tracing) and some shadertoy demonstrate recursive space raytracing that isn't marching. The benefit are multiple, but I need single O(1) trace for open gl es 2.0, notably fur. I could so the single point version, I just failed to generalized.

Comment: Including a link would be a great start on the path toward a solution then. So far as I'm aware, Claybook does use raymarching, but there may be other examples we can learn from

Comment: I have added to my former comment, but yes claybook do use raymarching, because the data is as good as random, BUT the dev did some experiment he shared on twitter, also the guy who made the blog demofox. I also linked the laser math problem that pose part of the problem, reposting here: https://amininima.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/the-laser-gun/

Comment: I had made further exploration here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/infinite-parallax-hair-volume-using-wrapping-grid-tracing-attempt.593233/ my main contribution is trying to get rid of the modulo by replacing it with a "beat synchronicity" system inspired by planet alignment/clock hand overlap math riddle
here is the original tweet of seb aaltonen of Claybook fame: https://twitter.com/SebAaltonen/status/784692080765464576

Comment: Note that the case in the tweet is 2D, so any primitive maps to a simple interval. This gets substantially more complex in 3D, where the "hit zone" can be a more complex shape that varies with the viewing angle. I wouldn't be surprised if there were a method to do this for spheres, and a different method for axis-aligned cubes, but I'd be surprised if you could find a single algorithm that would handle any 3D primitive interchangeably.

Comment: I'll be fine if it can't be generalized to all primitive in all orientation, I can make use of it in axis aligned version ... I feel like triangle can probably be done, if it's possible for 2d triangle? Sphere seems a bit "obvious", axis align cube and cylinder might be possible. The benefit is that it have a period we can find mathematically, we could probably infer an analytical "overdraw", by "discarding depth" have a "traversed thickness", if we generalized such as we can also shift the position of the primitive at each "jump", we could probably find a consistent "integral noise"

Comment: "the end goal" was at least 1 period coil repeated on axis aligned lol for dense afro textured hair. But we can't intersect cosine "cheaply", I tried using x² approximations but my math melted. A unit coil being an unwrap unit cylinder diagonal, was the next step explored, ie to intersect axis aligned cylinder then find on its surface the diagonal: https://forum.unity.com/attachments/cylindrical-jpg.491282/

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to render dense coiled hair, I expect you'll get to that result faster if you ask about it directly. Maybe analytical intersection might not be the most efficient route to good-looking hair rendering, so framing your question in that form might keep you from getting useful insights from other potential solution paths.

Comment: I do need and want the basic infinite tracing though, I have use for that too.... On hair I already tried and documented all existing technique, i'm well aware of all their shortcoming and cost, THIS would be just another tool. I'm documenting how to properly do 4C hair technically (with a complete new classification of its features), since there is literally no document on it and most of what's out there is bogus, incomplete or just ugly. There is obvious historical reason why that's the case lol. I just dropped about the coil as part as explaining all the potential use.

Comment: oh and i forgot the biggest benefit, is that, since it's analytic, I can do trick by passing parameters with the texture per pixel, which I already do with abusing a simpler form of interior design, by cranking the space between side low, and get dense foliage and grass for free, or brick walls, or any greebles. Except I'm confined to convex shapes, with this I could have more interesting parallax to abuse, I use the flow of the polygon surface to create interesting shapes, and UV texture to break pattern artistically. Work wonder for low specs machine! I'll update to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

**I haven't found a proper implementable solution yet**, but I think I'm getting very close, at least solving it visually, I just can't make the jump to the final implementation, I'm not good at math at all...

Initially I tried to simplify the problem to a point at the corner of the 2d grid. This essentially collapse the problem to 1d problem, if we project boundaries intercept of the ray on one of the axis, it turn into a series of points at regular interval, the solution is to find when one of these points overlap the corner position, basically it's like having two beats at different frequency and guessing when they play at the same time. Since we are now in 1d, I can assimilate the wrapping space to a circle, and suddenly the problem looks like the clock hands overlap problem (or the planet alignment problem)... TO WHICH google have some ready made solution for me, so by using the grid size as a rate and the ray delta as another we get a solution.

[image: 1d reduction]
[image: 1d circle equivalence]

**Points being infinitely small it's not very useful** yet, it was just about finding insight. That insight came in realizing that the solution is basically scaling the grid size by the step size to find a common period an, and dividing it by the difference of rates between the delta and the grid size, so grid size can be assimilate to a rate or period, the whole grid is basically a frequency.

That solution also looked an awful lot like a DDA used in raycasting old wolfenstein level (cell size/ray step). That's the second insight, that the DDA itself can be interpreted as a specific implementation of the recurrent primitive intersection problem, except that recurrent primitive is an axis aligned plan, we basically compute the recurrent intersection of the planes in the direction of the ray casted. And also we ONLY need to compute the set of primitive in the direction of the ray.

[image: circle DDA]

The intercept solution for a single sphere is to project the sphere center to the ray casted line, then use that point to compute a length to compare to the radius size, if the length is bigger we miss, otherwise it's a hit. In our case, the variation of that length across the grid should be the delta needed to compute the period of hit and miss, **ideally**.

When we look at the schema, the first insight is that ALL projection lines are parallel, and perpendicular to the ray, that evoke thales theorem a lot, and it seems to hint that the solution could be along simple trigonometry. However the inconsistent integer stepping of the "DDA" make it hard to generalize.

Up until I realize one thing that turn the whole thing much simpler, I only need to unwrap the space in the direction of the major axis, as it collapse the DDA to a single line using the wrapping of the ray casted, which mean we also have a new period of the vertical wrapping of the ray, everything become close to a 1D problem again ...

[image: 1d unwrapping]

First observation is that all projections lines (pink lines) are basically all the same, they have the same direction and goes through the same points in unwrap space. That mean they are all constant and can be reduce to a constant interval within the cell space, so we have 3 nested intervals: the cell size itself, the boundaries intercepts of the projection lines and the projected radius range along the projection line.

As noticed the ray boundaries intercepts define a constant range, BUT that range isn't synced to cell size and it's nested ranges. Also the ray range have varying offset relative to the cell position.

The solution lie in the delta of the recurrent intersection of the ray relative to the projection line. Basically since everything is linear, the delta SHOULD be constant, and therefore a simple stepping along the projection line distance. Basically dividing that distance (from the first hit on that line) by the computed delta, assuming the direction of the stepping also wrap nicely along the projection line (in the infinite unwrapped space the projection line does not).

It's basically like finding when the intersection get into the projected radius ranges. HOWEVER **a simple division don't define when the step JUMPS over the interval, I have no idea how to handle that specific case yet ...**

There is still an awful lot of thales and trigonometry looking structures, I just hasn't figured out how to properly find the relevant one yet ...

I'm almost there, the math don't look complicated, I just don't have the education to figure it out yet :(